# Oracle:external table throwing exception

Tags: plsql, oracle10g

I'm trying to execute this script that creates an external table for a file that i have outside the db. The script is as follows:

```
DECLARE

FILENAME VARCHAR2 := 'actual_data.txt';

BEGIN
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLE ACTUAL_DATA_1 (
  ID      NUMBER(5),
  MSISDN    VARCHAR2(20),
  RECHARGE_DATE DATE,
  RECAHRGE_AMOUNT  NUMBER(25)
)
ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL (
  TYPE ORACLE_LOADER
  DEFAULT DIRECTORY USER_DIR
  ACCESS PARAMETERS (
    RECORDS DELIMITED BY NEWLINE
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    MISSING FIELD VALUES ARE NULL
    (
  ID      NUMBER(5),
  MSISDN    VARCHAR2(20),
  RECHARGE_DATE DATE,
  RECAHRGE_AMOUNT  NUMBER(25)
    )
  )
  LOCATION (''' || FILENAME || ''')
)
PARALLEL 5
REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED;';
END;
/
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','

                          *
ERROR at line 17:
ORA-06550: line 17, column 27:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "," when expecting one of the following:
* & = - + ; < / > at in is mod remainder not rem return
returning <an exponent (**)> <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or
like LIKE2_ LIKE4_ LIKEC_ between into using || multiset bulk
member SUBMULTISET_

ORA-06550: line 29, column 25:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ";" when expecting one of the following:
) , * & | = - + < / > at in is mod remainder not rem => ..
<an exponent (**)> <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or like LIKE2_
LIKE4_ LIKEC_ between || member
```

Could somebody help out an oracle newbie?

Comment: You need to escape the single quotes inside the string using `''` https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements003.htm#SQLRF00220

Comment: Hi, i'm still not sure, how it has to come. So could you showcase it up as an answer?

Comment: I think i got it. I have to replace  `FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','` with `FIELDS TERMINATED BY '',''`. But i am getting a new exception.

Comment: For `FILENAME VARCHAR2 := 'actual_data.txt';` `ERROR at line 2:
ORA-06550: line 2, column 10:
PLS-00215: String length constraints must be in range (1 .. 32767)`. Could you take a look at this also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please specify the mandatory size for the VARCHAR2 defenition.

FILENAME VARCHAR2(n) := 'actual_data.txt';

And n can be bertween 1 .. 32767
Example :  FILENAME VARCHAR2(400) := 'actual_data.txt';